# Inherit active_record in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance, activerecord

Right now my classes are look like this.

```
class BalanceName < ActiveRecord
    def before_validation
      set_blank_attributes_to_nil(@attributes)
    end
end

class Balance < ActiveRecord
    def before_validation
      set_blank_attributes_to_nil(@attributes)
    end
end
```

I want to inherite activer record into one class and than want to inherite that class into other classes like.

I want something like this.

```
class CommonActiveRecord < ActiveRecord::Base

  def before_validation
    set_blank_attributes_to_nil(@attributes)
  end

end

class BalanceName < CommonActiveRecord
    def before_validation
      super
    end
end

class Balance < CommonActiveRecord
    def before_validation
      super
    end
end
```

Comment: @phil I want to create a common class which inherit ActiveRecord. And my other class will inherit that common class. In my question's second block, i have written a code i want something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do exactly as you have done except you do not need to redefine the `before_validation` methods in your subclasses (though I guess these may be here prior to being filled with more specific validation).

You will also need to indicate to rails that your `CommonActiveRecord` class is abstract and therefore is not persisted by adding:

```
class CommonActiveRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create module (e.g. lib/common_active_record.rb):

```
module CommonActiveRecord
  def before_validation
    set_blank_attributes_to_nil(@attributes)
  end
end
```

And then in your model simply include it:

```
class BalanceName < ActiveRecord::Base
  include CommonActiveRecord
end

class Balance < ActiveRecord::Base
  include CommonActiveRecord
end
```